# How to register root logins in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, server

My IT teacher asked me to help him with maintaining school site's remote server, and he wanted me to write a script to register who (ip addr) and when, logged in by root account, because he suspected that someone undesirable logs into the server. And there I've spotted the problem, generally site stands on phpmyadmin, I am pythonist and meant that I've never used phpmyadmin to manage websites. I would not take this task but I thought about SO society.
Referring to foregoing issue, have you any idea how I can do it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you just change the root password so this "undesirable" person can't get in anymore?

Comment: He want catch that person then change root password.

Comment: Maybe take a look at https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/668/audit-logins-on-mysql-database. Not really a PHP question..

Comment: If no one else should have access to PHPMyAdmin, you can check the webserver logs for the IP for unfamiliar IPs.

Comment: Not a PHP question really, but hardly worth a downvote. I feel. it might help people understand the information_schema database inside mysql. Interesting stuff out there.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution is 
a) Change the root password.
b) Create a new set of users.
c) Just track who does what and identify the undesirable. 
d) Block the user after it is done.

Ofcourse, if you still want to track ipaddress of root users, here is, the option.This query works for active logins only.
Use this query to track every login and write a db trigger to store the host in a file or another table.

```
select host from information_schema.processlist;
```

Hope this helps.